# Python Pandas Match Vlookup columns based on header values

Tags: python, pandas, match, lookup

I have the following dataframe df:

```
Customer_ID | 2015 | 2016 |2017 | Year_joined_mailing
ABC            5      6     10     2015
BCD            6      7     3      2016        
DEF            10     4     5      2017
GHI            8      7     10     2016
```

I would like to look up the value of the customer in the year they joined the mailing list and save it in a new column.

Output would be:

```
Customer_ID | 2015 | 2016 |2017 | Year_joined_mailing | Purchases_1st_year
ABC            5      6     10     2015                       5
BCD            6      7     3      2016                       7       
DEF            10     4     5      2017                       5
GHI            8      9     10     2016                       9
```

I have found some solutions for match vlookup in python, but none that would use the headers of other columns.

Comment: the lookup is the columns 2015, 2016 and 2017

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> **Deprecation Notice**: `lookup` was [deprecated in v1.2.0](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v1.2.0.html#deprecations)

Use [**`pd.DataFrame.lookup`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html)
Keep in mind that I'm assuming `Customer_ID` is the index.

```
df.lookup(df.index, df.Year_joined_mailing)

array([5, 7, 5, 7])
```

---

```
df.assign(
    Purchases_1st_year=df.lookup(df.index, df.Year_joined_mailing)
)

             2015  2016  2017  Year_joined_mailing  Purchases_1st_year
Customer_ID                                                           
ABC             5     6    10                 2015                   5
BCD             6     7     3                 2016                   7
DEF            10     4     5                 2017                   5
GHI             8     7    10                 2016                   7
```

---

However, you have to be careful with comparing possible strings in the column names and integers in the first year column...

Nuclear option to ensure type comparisons are respected.

```
df.assign(
    Purchases_1st_year=df.rename(columns=str).lookup(
        df.index, df.Year_joined_mailing.astype(str)
    )
)

             2015  2016  2017  Year_joined_mailing  Purchases_1st_year
Customer_ID                                                           
ABC             5     6    10                 2015                   5
BCD             6     7     3                 2016                   7
DEF            10     4     5                 2017                   5
GHI             8     7    10                 2016                   7
```

Comment: magic ... didn't think it was possible in a one-liner - THANK YOU

Comment: Thank you - it worked for one column, but for my second one in the same dataframe, I get this error KeyError: 'One or more column labels was not found' - could it be related to index? I set Customer_ID to index df = df.set_index(['Customer_ID'])

Answer (score 3):

you can apply "apply" to each row

```
df.apply(lambda x: x[x['Year_joined_mailing']],axis=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

I would do it like this, assuming that the column headers and the `Year_joined_mailing` are the same data type and that all `Year_joined_mailing` values are valid columns. If the datatypes are not the same, you could convert it by adding `str()` or `int()` where appropriate.

```
df['Purchases_1st_year'] = [df[df['Year_joined_mailing'][i]][i] for i in df.index]
```

What we're doing here is iterating over the indexes in the dataframe to get the `'Year_joined_mailing'` field for that index, then using that to get the column we want, and again selecting that index from the column, pushing it all to a list and assigning this to our new column `'Year_joined_mailing'`

If your `'Year_joined_mailing'` column will not always be a valid column name, then try:

```
from numpy import nan
new_col = []
for i in df.index:
    try:
        new_col.append(df[df['Year_joined_mailing'][i]][i])
    except IndexError:
        new_col.append(nan) #or whatever null value you want here)
df['Purchases_1st_year'] = new_col
```

This longer code snippet accomplishes the same thing, but will not break if `'Year_joined_mailing'` is not in `df.columns`

Comment: Thank you very much - this worked as well; so I upvoted it